# Drupal 7 - Adding Nodes Through phpmyadmin is not Working Correctly

Tags: ms-access, drupal-7, phpmyadmin

I have received a Microsoft Access database file and was tasked to convert the contents into something readable by mySQL standards for a Drupal 7 website database. I managed to upload them into the "node" table successfully, with the correct content type classification, unique primary keys and node IDs, etc. Or so I thought.

When I checked the Drupal site, I checked the list of content type X, and all of the new stuff was there. However, when I tried to click them, instead of opening the new page like I expected it to, I received a "page not found" message, instead. I tried looking for the new content manually via "Find Content", but none of it was showing up. I checked entity reference lists that referenced content type X, but they were not showing up on those lists, either.

I checked which fields were required for content type X, and I found that "location category" and "address" were required fields. So to test, I only added 1 entry to each of those tables (both field_data and field_revision versions of the required field), representing the 1st of the many I tried to transfer over. Still nothing. I have no idea what I could be doing wrong. Can anyone offer some insight?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding content to Drupal through the database is absolutely the wrong way to go about creating content. I suggest you try any of the following methods:

1. Create the nodes programmatically using Drupal's API functions:
   http://fooninja.net/2011/04/13/guide-to-programmatic-node-creation-in-drupal-7/
2. Upload data through a CSV file using the Feeds module:
   http://drupal.org/project/feeds/

Comment: I'm trying the Feeds module right now. I downloaded the node template they offered and followed it to enter the data that I needed to. I added in additional heads (like type, status, created, etc.) And then imported with Feeds. It seemed to have worked, but when I checked, they were all of type "article" even though I specified what type they were all supposed to be. I changed them to be type "charities" via phpmyadmin. It looked like it worked, but when I try to edit one of the new nodes, I see the "Edit X" title but nothing is displaying underneath it.

Comment: Honestly I dont ever try to hack the database, you can undo/redo a feeds import if it goes wrong